# WebView with images - adjusting default zoom level

Tags: android, webview, android-imageview, android-image

I have a problem with default zoom on WebView. When I load the URL I have my image not adjusted to screen (it is too small and it is in the right-top side).

I would like to have the initial zoom like in ImageView.

This is my actual code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webView=new WebView(this);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.loadUrl(URL);
    LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    addContentView(webView, params);       
}
```

and I get this effect with it:

[image: Screenshot]

I would like to have it looks like this (I got it using ImageView):

[image: Screenshot]

How can I get this effect using WebView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check two things:

1. First your html is probably just `<img src="...">`, right?  You'll probably have to style the image to fit the width of the screen. ([see this](http://unstoppablerobotninja.com/entry/fluid-images))  Instead of using an image tag you could also set the background of the html to use that image ([see this](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/))
2. The other thing that might be happening is your WebView isn't filling the screen... but that seems unlikely.

Comment: Actually, I open directly the jpg file. It is webView.loadUrl(URL); , where String URL = http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/7033/79920970.jpg

Comment: I see.  Well then, much like you don't have much control over how the browser renders an image url, you don't have much control how a webview renders that image.  You can just set the content of the webview to some html that renders the image in an image tag the way you want it though.